# Find cause of error "constraint xxxx is not a foreign key constraint" in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have defined these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "public".category (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX category_name ON "public".category (name);

CREATE TABLE "public".clusters (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE INDEX clusters_name ON "public".clusters (name);

CREATE TABLE "public".keywords (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, text varchar(255) NOT NULL, category_id int8 NOT NULL, top_results int4, cluster_id int8, month_requests int4, click_cost float8, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE INDEX keywords_text ON "public".keywords (text);
ALTER TABLE "public".keywords ADD CONSTRAINT FKkeywords488682 FOREIGN KEY (cluster_id) REFERENCES "public".clusters (id);
ALTER TABLE "public".keywords ADD CONSTRAINT FKkeywords446526 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES "public".category (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

added one record to category table:

```
INSERT INTO "public".category(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Test');
```

And now when I try to add record to keyword table

```
insert into "public"."keywords" ( "category_id", "text") values ( 1, 'testkey')
```

I got error:

> ERROR:  constraint 16959 is not a foreign key constraint

When I do

```
select * FROM pg_constraint;
```

I can't see constraint with this id. I can't understand what is the cause of this problem.

Comment: Try to drop constraints then recreate it again. I can't see any error in your code, it works well on [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3f90b/1)

Comment: Your example works for me, too.

Comment: This could be data corruption. The entry in `pg_constraint` that belongs to the foreign key is not a foreign key constraint.